# Android : How to know the ip connected to my hotspot in android

Tags: android, networking, ip, hotspot

How to know the ip connected to my hotspot in android

I try to under code but /proc/net/arp is not reachable file in android 10
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#proc-net-filesystem

```
BufferedReader br = null;
                final ArrayList<ClientScanResult> result = new ArrayList<ClientScanResult>();

                try {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));

                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] splitted = line.split(" +");

                        if ((splitted != null) && (splitted.length >= 4)) {
                            // Basic sanity check
                            String mac = splitted[3];

                            if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                                boolean isReachable = InetAddress.getByName(splitted[0]).isReachable(reachableTimeout);

                                if (!onlyReachables || isReachable) {
                                    result.add(new ClientScanResult(splitted[0], splitted[3], splitted[5], isReachable));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.toString());
                } finally {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It is unclear if you want to know the ip of the hotspot or of the device connected to the hotspot.

Comment: I want to know device ip connected to the hotspot

Comment: The wifi manager will tell you.